# Implement History Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, history

I want to implement history functionality in my application, but I want to skip
creating history data table for every business object data table.

I was thinking about creating one history data table, that contain one identity column and an XML column with changed data as follow

```
ID: int
XML: Data
Name: data table name
```

Is this approach implemented by someone or do you see any constraints about this architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a modified version of this article - [Adding simple trigger-based auditing to your SQL Server database](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database) - for years now.

It uses the old `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views since it relies on the column position which isn't available in any of the newer DMVs (e.g. `sys.tables`, `sys.columns`). Other than that it flies and works like a charm.

If performance becomes a problem - and this is rare - you can consider using Service Broker to implement asynchronous triggers for writing to the history table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using 2008, you can try to use [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx).

Comment: This is not appropriate for a history table as the data is purged every three days by default.

Comment: It can be configured with [sys.sp_cdc_change_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510748.aspx)

Comment: But most people don;t know that which is why I brought it up

Comment: Generally Change data capture doesn't capture everything you need in a history or audit table either, espceially if you want to store who made the change. We only use it for checking to see if a record we are importing has been changed by the application. It isn;t flexible enough for any other purpose, we have found.